# Grails 2.4.5 org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: No Session found for current thread

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to call another service (serviceB) method m2 from serviceA method m1. In method m2, a domain object is saved to db, and at that time it throws "Session not found for the current thread" error. If I call the api for m2, it goes as expected. In method m2 I am using withSession, withTransaction multiple times.
Before calling m2 in m1, I am saving domain object and it is getting updated successfully without any error.
Before save call, GORM is able to fetch data from db, but in next line (save with flush), it does not get the session.
I am using Grails 2.4.5, java version is jdk 1.8, database is PostgresSql.

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: No Session found for current thread; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:216)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertHibernateAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:192)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:132)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi.withNewSession(HibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:515)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi$withNewSession$2.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
```